# focusin event triggers in IE for floated and Inline Block element

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

The `focusin` event which is a part of form inputs and link tag,  is getting applied for `div` and `span` tags. It happens for floated and inline-block element. The issue is spotted in  IE (8 and 9).

Demo ==> http://jsfiddle.net/Agczq/

Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Why does this affect your site? Please include a [small example](http://sscce.org) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: sample can be found here => http://jsfiddle.net/Agczq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike you might expect `focusin` and `focusout` do bubble up, unlike the regular `focus` event. The two main ways of dealing with this are: Event delegation, or simply stopping the event from bubbling up.

Your fiddle is hard to make sense of (ie: don't know what you're trying to do). The first thing that comes to mind (after moving your JS code to the JavaScript field on jsfiddle) is that you're capturing a `focus` event in good browsers, and the bubbling `focusin` in crummy IE. 
This can be quite annoying, particularly since IE doesn't support actual event capturing. Nevertheless, here's a (simple, but tested and working) suggestion:

```
function mycb(evt)
{
    evt = evt || window.event;//get event object
    var from = evt.target || evt.srcElement;//get source
    if (evt.stopPropagation)//stop event from bubbling
    {
        evt.stopPropagation();//shouldn't be necessary, but you never know
    }
    else
    {
        evt.cancelBubble = true;//stop propagation in IE-lingo
    }
    if (from.tagName === 'DIV' || from.tagName === 'SPAN')
    {//if source was a tag that souldn't fire event, return false;
        if (evt.preventDefault)
        {
            evt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        evt.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }
     alert("fired!!!");
}

var elem = document.getElementById("mybox");
if( elem.attachEvent )
{
    elem.attachEvent("onfocusin",  mycb);
}
else
{
    elem.addEventListener("focus", mycb, true);
}
```

This code was tested in IE8, fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xdjf5/). 
It just so happens I read about this event today, [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html). A source worth mentioning, I reckon.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Elias, Thanks for the reply, but this is a general solution by turning off the default, but did you notice   onfocus[in|out] will be bubbling  if the element is floated, but works fine by setting the display property to inline. In my example http://jsfiddle.net/Agczq/ by removing the float property in  container class the event will not bubbles.

Comment: I assumed you want prevent the default behaviour, since you're capturing the event in non IE browsers. I don't quite follow as to what you mean when you say the event doesn't bubble, though. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536935(v=vs.85).aspx) reference states, quite clearly this event bubbles - full stop. Could you provide a fiddle where the event doesn't bubble? perhaps that might shed some light on the matter

Comment: Thanks Again, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8tjaf/   only difference here is , just taken out the style.

Comment: Ow, now I see... well, according to the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530755(v=vs.85).aspx), floating elements need a width property to be rendered (and behave) as expected. I tried adding a `style="width:"100px;"` attribute to the `#mybox` element, which seemed to me to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, interesting question to look into, too +1!